# Google analytics not tracking when tag is changed from text/plain to text/javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Soo, now with all the GDPR, and opt-in cookie boxes, i have run in to a small issue..

I have set my google analytics code into a javascript file, and added it to my layout :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Google/analytics.js" class="cookie-script" type="text/plain"></script>
```

I have it set to text/plain in the beginning, and then i have some other script that checks if you have accepted cookies.

When you have accepted cookies, it will change it to text/javascript.
It also checks at page load if you have already accepted and then changes it to text/javascript..

My issue... 
It does not appear it is tracking correctly with google analytics.. 
Can analytics not figure out to track once it has been "activated" ?

How to overcome this, so i can still get my data ?

in my analytics account, i have taken the code it says to include in my head element. But no data makes it through...

Answer (score -2):

It does not cause problems, if the intent is that browsers do not interpret the content of the element as script code but just as text data that is not rendered. It’s there for scripts to use it, but otherwise it’s ignored. Well, in some browsers, the content might be made visible using CSS, but by default it’s not shown.

Using  is valid by HTML specs. Even  is valid, though it violates the prose requirement that the attribute value be a MIME type. The specs do not specify its meaning, but the only feasible interpretation, and what browsers do in practice, is that it is not in any scripting language and no execution as script is attempted.

So type="text/plain" may be used to intentionally prevent execution of a script, while still keeping it in the source. It may also be used to carry bulks of character data used for some processing.

The type attribute may serve purposes like this, and it can also be used to specify scripting languages other than JavaScript (rarely used, but still possible in some environments). Using the type attribute just to specify JavaScript is not needed, and cannot be recommended: the only thing that you might achieve is errors: if you mistype, e.g. type="text/javascript", the content will be regarded as being in an unknown language, hence ignored.

Comment: So what should i do to get the same functionality and get my analytics to work?

Comment: please check this https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingOverview

Comment: I tried adding the first code , and added my key, and i still do not show up in analytics.